# Bash crontab doesn't output products of shell script file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cron

Hi I'm a first year game programing student learning Unix Bash, I have run into a problem trying to understand crontab. I'm trying to do some rather simple things, checking to see if I am online, getting information about a given website, and ping another website to verify it is online. My script file does all of this without fail, however when I try to perform these tasks through crontab I get emails telling me absolutely nothing but jibberish. The output basically just tells me that I am trying to do all these things, but it doesn't output the results. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.
Just to verify I do have permission on the system to use crontab, and I have the script running every minute while I am trying to get it working. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction, all of my research online has really just led me astray.

This is my crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/
LOGNAME=username

* * * * * /bin/bash /home/students/~/online.sh

30 23 1 * * rm online.log
```

this is my script

```
touch online.log
who | grep username >> online.log ; whois yahoo.ca >> online.log ; ping -c 1 www.google.com >> online.log
```

Comment: Is really just jibberish? Normally those emails sent by cron are your first clue to debug problems like this. And btw the `~` there in the middle of `/home/students/~/online.sh` looks like jibberish :p

Comment: lol, yes very true, but for the sake of privacy I thought it best to omit my username and other identifying portions of the code I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute paths in your scripts if you want to execute those using `cron`.

Note that `cron` executes in a different environment from what you get while executing a script on the command line.  For example, changes lines like

```
touch online.log
```

to include the *absolute path* to `online.log`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was totally my problem, the worst part is that I had just read what you said in another post a few minutes earlier and it just didn't click in! Much appreciated! @devnull

Answer (score 0):

The output is being redirected into `online.log`, so you need to look there, not in your emails. If you want the output to be in the emails as well, you should look into using `tee` instead of a redirection.

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't send the output to online.log, instead it sends me emails to /var/spool/mail/username, I'd love if it would send the output to online.log, that would be a step up from where I am now.